# SPSS: Can I generate graphs for multiple variables using a single syntax input with the GRAPH command?

Tags: syntax, graph, spss

I was wondering if it was possible to create graphs for multiple variables in a single syntax command in SPSS:

```
GRAPH
/HISTOGRAM(NORMAL)=
```

As it is, I'm creating multiple graphs as such:

```
GRAPH
/HISTOGRAM(NORMAL)=CO

GRAPH
/HISTOGRAM(NORMAL)=Min_last

GRAPH
/HISTOGRAM(NORMAL)=Day_abs
```

etc etc.

If I would do something along the lines of:

```
GRAPH
/HISTOGRAM(NORMAL)=CO Min_last Day_abs
```

and it would generate a graph for each variable, I'd be pretty happy.

Anyways, let me know if you think it's possible or if I need to provide more info. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I like to do it is to reshape the data so all three variables are in the same row using `VARSTOCASES` and then either panel the charts in small multiples (if you want the axes to be the same) or use `SPLIT FILES` to produce seperate charts. Example of the split file approach below:

```
*Making fake data.
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP #i = 1 TO 100.
  COMPUTE CO = RV.NORMAL(0,1).
  COMPUTE Min_last = RV.UNIFORM(0,1).
  COMPUTE Days_abs = RV.POISSON(5).
  END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.

*Reshaping to long.
VARSTOCASES /MAKE V FROM CO Min_last Days_abs /INDEX VLab (V).

*Split file and build seperate charts.
SORT CASES BY VLab.
SPLIT FILE BY VLab.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=V
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: V=col(source(s), name("V"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Value"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Frequency"))
  ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.count(bin.rect(V))), shape.interior(shape.square))
END GPL.
SPLIT FILE OFF.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just to save typing and want an independent set of graphs, you can define a macro like this.

define !H (!positional !cmdend)
!do !i !in (!1)
graph /histogram(normal)=!i.
!doend
!enddefine.

and invoke it with a list of variables.

!H salary salbegin.